# Selecting from drop down list Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

This is part of website code related to this question
[image: This is part of website code related to this question]

I have trouble here to identify drop down list, actually i cant find a xpath of this drop down element and select first (and only) element from drop down list.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Assign to a member']"));
```

This is my xpath for field, but nothing happens when start working. 
Anyone to suggest me how to approach to this issue.

Comment: Drop down list is "Assign to a member" part

Comment: Post the relevant mark-up as well.

Comment: You need to edit your question and post the relevant HTML **as text**, not a screenshot.

Comment: Your locator is locating an `INPUT`, not a `SELECT` or some other element that is mocking a dropdown. That's probably the first issue. Can you post a link to the page so we can see? With what you've posted, it's going to be near impossible to figure this out. If your page doesn't have a true `SELECT` element, you will need to find and click the "dropdown" element and then click on the option you want once the list is open and displayed.

Comment: **http://test.squadin.xyz/employer/tickets** 
Username:**o2842914@nwytg.net**
Password: **o6JoofAj**

Place when adding new ticket and assigning to one of the members.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: How do you click this element ? Please share more code/

Comment: 'String searchUserXpath = "//div[@class='selectize-input items has-options not-full focus input-active dropdown-active']";
  String optionName = "Testing Subscriptions";
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(searchUserXpath )).sendKeys("Testing Subscriptions");
  driver.findElement(By.name(optionName));'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in Java, you need to create a select element to choose the options of the select.

The code will be somenthing like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Assign to a member']"));

String option = "Option value you want to select";
Select select = new Select(element);
select.selectByVisibleText(option);
```

Comment: If you look at the HTML, it's not a `SELECT` element.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, your comment code helped me for other things to select other things on webpage. Only what is my concern now that i cant find and click on dropdown list, i giving me a 3-4 different xpaths but none of them are not working. I am not willing to share publicly whole website.